# Why does the following program not generate any visible output?

Tags: c, printf

The following C program doesn't printing anything on the screen.

I compiled the program with `gcc`:

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
    printf("hai");
    for(;;);
}
```

Comment: Yes it doesn't, and what is your question?

Answer (score 9):

Most likely, `stdout` is line buffered. Your program does not call [`fflush`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/fflush.html) or send a newline so the buffer does not get written out.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("hai\n");
    for(;;)
    ;
    return 0;
}
```

See also [question 12.4](http://c-faq.com/stdio/fflush.html) and [What's the correct declaration of main()?](http://c-faq.com/ansi/maindecl.html) in the [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/).

Comment: Why the downvote? Failure to include `return 0` from a function that never returns?

Comment: @faceless I had missed the typo originally. Human brains are like that: They do automatic error correction when you least want them to. It would have been nice of you to point out that I had missed the typo when you downvoted my answer.

Answer (score 4):

This is caused by the buffering which takes place in stdio (i.e. it is not output immediately unless you tell it to by including a \n or fflush). Please refer to [Write to stdout and printf output not interleaved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242974/write-to-stdout-and-printf-output-not-interleaved) which explains this.

(p.s. or the compiler is not happy about the typo in #include)

Answer (score 3):

Standard output tends to be line buffered by default so the reason you're not seeing anything is because you haven't flushed the line.

This will work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (int argC, char *argV[])
{
    printf("hai\n");
    for(;;)
        ;
    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, you could `fflush` standard out or just get rid of the infinite loop so the program exits:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (int argC, char *argV[])
{
    printf("hai");
    return 0;
}
```

but you probably want the newline there anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Your for(;;) loop stops the stream from being flushed. As others have suggested, add a newline to the string being output, or flush the stream explicitly:

```
fflush( stdout );
```

after your printf. And correct the spelling of #include.