# Strange Behaviour because of sleep()

Tags: c

I was just getting familiar with sleep(), i found that

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
int i=0;
printf("*********Testing Sleep***********\n");
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    printf("%d",i);
    sleep(1);
}
return 0;
```

}

this does not print number per iteration rather dumps all numbers when gets out of loop....
but when i modify printf...

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
int i=0;
printf("*********Testing Sleep***********\n");
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    printf("%d\n",i);
    sleep(1);
}
return 0;
```

}

and now as i've added '\n' new line it works as expected... why it is behaving strangely in former one...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because the output buffer isn't being flushed (in other words, actually committed to the terminal). When you write a newline, the output buffer is more likely to be (but still not always, in some cases) flushed. Many terminal implementations do this to improve performance. To force the behaviour you want, you need to call `fflush(stdout);` after each `printf` call, like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
int i=0;
printf("*********Testing Sleep***********\n");
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    printf("%d",i);
    fflush(stdout);
    sleep(1);
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Instead of calling `fflush()` every time, he could also call `setvbuf( stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0 )` at the beginning of his program to make `stdout` unbuffered.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking at is *line buffered output*. Actually writing to output is an expensive operation, so I/O streams are usually *buffered*. Actually writing the buffer is deferred until a specific event is encountered. In standard C, you have three types of buffering:

- fully buffered - the buffer is written when full.
- line buffered - the buffer is written when a newline is encountered (your case).
- unbuffered - the buffer is written whenever an I/O function is executed. (Good for error logging.)

Writing the buffer is called *flushing*. That's why there is a stdio function called `fflush()`. You might also want to check out `setvbuf()` and its parameter constants, `_IOFBF`, `_IOLBF` and `_IONBF`. I am sure you can figure out what they mean *without* looking them up. ;-)

**Edit:** This program delivers as you originally expected:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// This is the header where sleep() is declared. Don't go without it.
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int i=0;

    // setvbuf() can be called on a stream only BEFORE
    // you do any I/O on it!
    setvbuf( stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0 );

    printf( "*********Testing Sleep***********\n" );
    for ( i = 0; i < 10; ++i )
    {
        printf( "%d", i );
        sleep( 1 );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

standard output for terminals is line buffered, output is not written unless there is a newline or you manually flush it.

Comment: Actually there is no guarantee that your output is line buffered. It might just as well be fully buffered (i.e. when the environment can determine that your output is non-interactive, it is allowed to run I/O at fully buffered). But yes, line buffered is the most common.

Comment: yes, if you write to a file or a pipe and not to a terminal it's going to be fully buffered (not written until buffer is full).

Comment: *If* the environment can assert it actually *is* a file or pipe. Implementations are at liberty to use `_IOLBF` if in doubt.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `printf()` uses buffered output for better performance. Buffer is flushed to the console once `\n` is printed.

Answer (score 0):

Output is buffered, so that that the OS has an opportunity to optimize output speed. To make sure they are flushed immediately, do `fflush (stdout);`, but usually, you don't.

Answer (score 0):

Printf is buffered.

You can force printf to 'flush' its buffer using the fflush call.

Or

Simply push the buffer to stdout using \n as in your case .

More detailed discussion is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242974/write-to-stdout-and-printf-output-not-interleaved)