# Ho to write logs in Docker container

Tags: docker, logging

I made most simple C application which just printing a message:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(){
    int i = 0;
    while(1) {
        sleep(1);
        printf("sleeping ... %d\n", i++);
    }
}
```

Then, made a simplest possible Dockerfile for it:

```
FROM fedora

USER root
WORKDIR /root

ADD sleep-play .

CMD ["/root/sleep-play"]
```

Then, run that container as simple as it could:

```
sudo docker build -t sleeping .
sudo docker run --name sleeping -d sleeping
```

Finally I'm expecting to see my **stdout** output, **but nothing happens**:

```
sudo docker logs -f sleeping
## nothing shown!
```

From [here:](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/view_container_logs/)

> ... By default, docker logs shows the command’s STDOUT and STDERR.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What happend when you try to start the container in the foreground without "-d"?

Comment: @hannes91 exactly the same, just nothing! But the executable going well in host environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure, my best guess is that printf is buffered and maybe the buffer will not flush automaticly here.

Try to flush it manually:

```
fflush(stdout)
```

See also this related Stackoverflow entry for flushing manual printf statements: 
[write() to stdout and printf output not interleaved?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242974/write-to-stdout-and-printf-output-not-interleaved)

Answer (score 1):

I reproduced it and figured out that the **sleep** command is your problem. At the moment i dont know the exactly cause of this but without the sleep command it runs.

Maybe this article can help you: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/2838#issuecomment-194054757