# Why write() executes immediately, but printf() not?

Tags: c

I read and understood C executes a program **sequentially**, from top to bottom.
So, for instance, this easy function:

```
int main(void)
{
    int i;

    i = -1;
    while (++i < 5)
        printf("%i\n", i);
    printf("end\n");
    return (0);
}
```

will return:

```
0
1
2
3
4
end
```

But, I had a couple of cases yet where this has not happened, and I'm not able to understand why...
For instance here I would expect to have a "!" **before** each of the if/else result (so before "o" or "."), but all the "!" are printed at the **end**:

```
int     g_lines = 12;
int     g_columns = 34;
char    g_vacio = '.';
char    g_obstaculo = 'o';
char    g_lleno = 'x';

void print_map(void)
{
    int     line;
    int     col;

    line = 0;
    while (line <= g_lines - 1)
    {
        col = 0;
        while (col < g_columns)
        {
            printf("!");
            if (col % 2 == 0)
                write(1, &g_lleno, 1);
            else
                write(1, &g_vacio, 1);
            col++;
        }
        write(1, "\n", 1);
        line++;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.
x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.
x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.
x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.
x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.
x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.
x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.
x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.
x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.
x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.
x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.
x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

What's the reason why the "!" is printed just at the end?

I decided to exchange `printf("!")` with ````write(1, "!", 1)`````and now, surprisingly, the result is how expected.

```
        while (col < g_columns)
        {
            write(1, "!", 1);
            if (col % 2 == 0)
                write(1, &g_lleno, 1);
            else
                write(1, &g_vacio, 1);
            col++;
        }
```

now the output is:

```
!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.
!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.
!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.
!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.
!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.
!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.
!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.
!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.
!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.
!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.
!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.
!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.!x!.
```

Can anybody explain why?

Comment: I had a doubt just after posting the comment, so I decided to replace ````printf```` with ````write```` and now the behaviour is the one I expected. I'll edit the question to try to find a reason for that.

Comment: Buffers.  `printf` keeps data in a buffer until it is full and then calls `write` to output it.  You are calling `write` directly in some cases, bypassing the buffer.

Comment: Yes, dupe. Deleted my answer and voted to close as dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242974/write-to-stdout-and-printf-output-not-interleaved

Comment: Using `fwrite` instead of `write` would also solve the problem. It's not a good idea to mix the standard IO functions and the POSIX ones.